# Генерировать новый одномерный объект от многомерного объекта

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, во общем есть многомерный объект из него извлекаю нужные элементы и записываю на новый объект:

> ```
> getArrayForCheckB:function(ind,a){
>     var newObj = new Object;
>     if(OBJ != '')
>     OBJ.forEach(function(e,i) {
>         newObj[i] = e.l[ind].s[0][a];  
>     });
>     return newObj;
> }
> ```

всё вроде генерирует, в DOM вижу как объект, но когда делаю так:

> ```
> alert(newObj.length); //undefined
> ```

выдает undefined, а мне надо еще с этим объектом работать в цикле

> ```
> for(...i>newObj.length ...){...}
> ```

а из этой проблемы цикл не работает, от чего так? подскажите чё как

Comment: пока в ручную добавил отдельный элемент length пока ответа не узнаю. 
Индусский код помогает)

Answer (score 1):

У объектов нету length вообще в принципе (тем более, что есть некоторая неясность, как называть количество элементов, в т.ч. методов, а как - количество "классических" свойств). Вы можете залезть в прототип и написать небольшой велосипед:

```
Object.prototype.getLength = function() {
    var length = 0;
    for (i in this) {
        if (typeof(this[i]) !== 'function') {
            length++;
        }
    }
    return length;
}
```

(Наверняка есть способы покрасивей - я в js на самом деле ни в зуб ногой, отдельно отмечу, что при таком подходе в цикле будет i, равный 'getLength', без проверки на метод длина была бы всегда не меньше единицы).